# DDR3, Data Mask Pin-swap within a given byte lane

Tags: ram, ddr3

Is it possible to swap "Data Mask" or "Data Strobe" pins with DQx pins within the same byte lane.

In Freescale's "Hardware and Layout Design Considerations for DDR3 SDRAM Memory Interfaces" app note, it is stated as "Pin-swap within a given byte lane to optimize the data bus routes further."

A byte lane comprises of 8 Data Bits, 1 Data Mask Bit, and 2 Data Strobe Bits.
As I understood for example, I can swap DQ2 pin with data mask bit or data strobe bits within the same byte lane...

I am confused because in all the examples on the internet, the data pins(DQx pins) have been swapped **only** in themselves.

Comment: You can swap DQ[0:7] with in them, but we can't swap any of DDR with DQS/DM. same way DQS with DM also.

Comment: @user19579 DQ[0] cannot be swapped if you are using read / write levelling.

Comment: @Peter: that depends on controller's capability. we are swapping DQ0 also in our designs.